# Syslog server on Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, syslog, syslog4j

We need to implement a syslog server on Java EE (running on WebLogic Server).

This seems to require an inbound resource adapter for the Java EE Connector Architecture (see [A J2EE syslog server?](https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/a-j2ee-syslog-server.505551/)).

Is there already an implementation of a JCA resource adapter for inbound syslog messages (e.g. based on Syslog4j)?

Comment: Take a look http://www.dodccrp.org/events/10th_ICCRTS/CD/papers/238.pdf